# What is the real potential energy of an alternating q and -q infinity system?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, physics, mathematical-physics, paradoxes

We can create a model of an infinite one-dimensional ionic crystal. Considering a system of $N\gg1$ alternating point charges $Q$ and $-Q$, that are distributed as the distance between two neighboring charges is given by $a$.

[See the figure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD0h5.png)

If we calculate the potential on a spot of a positive charge will get

$$V=2\left(-\dfrac{kQ}{a}+\dfrac{kQ}{2a}-\dfrac{kQ}{3a}+\dfrac{kQ}{4a}-...\right)$$

$$V=-\dfrac{2kQ}{a}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{5}-...\right)$$

Then our challange is calculate the sum

$$S=\sum^\infty_1\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$

If we make the sum in the following order

$$S=1-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{5}-...$$

We get

$$S=\ln2$$

However the sum $S$ is a conditionally convergent serie and by Riemann's theorem the result of the sum depend on the order that we make, for example, if we get

$$S=1+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}-\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{1}{13}+\dfrac{1}{15}-\dfrac{1}{6}-\dfrac{1}{8}+...$$

The result is

$$S=\dfrac{3}{2}\ln2$$

For more details of Riemann's theorem and alternating divergent series, see [this link](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/the-mind-boggling-properties-of-the-alternating-harmonic-series-d5e91a53dcfa).

Then the potential in a  spot depends on how i makes the sum? How to explain physically this result and which value i would find if i make the experiment?

Comment: Perhaps the way to interpret this is that the if you have finitely many point charges equally spaced and then take the limit as your number of particle goes to infinity. You can get a different series by considering different sequence of arrangements by filling out in different ways but perhaps, this isn't very natural.

Comment: Are you wanting to find the total potential energy of the charge configuration? Or the electric potential at some point? Title suggests the former but your expression with $Q$ rather than $Q^2$ suggests the latter

Comment: Have you see Purcell's E&M that book has this exact Q I think

Comment: Your sum $S$ omits the infinite term that corresponds to the charge right at the point you're considering.

Answer (score 1):

For a line of charge, the potential difference between points at finite and infinite radius is $\infty$. See [AccidentalFourierTransform's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/311632/85443). The divergence is the same for a line of point charges, so the difference is indeterminate.
Infinite systems are unphysical idealizations. However, if you start with finite $N$ and keep adding charges equally to both ends, you should get a finite limit.